# Notifications in Facebook

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, events

In Facebook. you get notifications, when somebody sends you a message. This is done without the user doing nothing. How is it triggered?

Can I achieve something like that using jsp, jQuery - ajax ?

How is that possible. Because I normally do things based on key press, or when user refreshes his browser. How can you know when that you receive a message?

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty methods for a server to send messages to a client. Some are:

- "Comet", where  `XmlHttpRequest`'s `onreadystatechange` is (ab)used to allow the server to 'stream' events, notifications, and other live data to the browser. This is now deprecated, but is the most compatible method. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))
- WebSockets, which allows a HTML5-compatible browser and an appropriate web server to establish a two-way socket. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets
- Server-sent events, like WebSockets, and only available in some browsers. These, unlike WebSockets, do not need a specialised webserver, but only allow the server to push events to the browser, not vice versa. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events

I would suggest using the jQuery EventSource plugin, which uses server-sent events when available, and, when not available, falls back to Comet: https://github.com/rwldrn/jquery.eventsource

Comment: If you can install software on your server I can only recommend you to use [A.P.E (Ajax Push Engine)](http://www.ape-project.org/) which provides a really scalable realtime server written in C and a javascript library that's crossbrowser to use it in your web applications :) It's stable and I used it with success in multiple projects.

Comment: I guess we could mention [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) which look really promising ... I didn't use it because I think it's not mature enough to use it in big production applications ...

Comment: Finally this wouldn't be complete if we didn't mention [TornadoWeb](http://www.tornadoweb.org/), the non-blocking server developed by facebook to handle their realtime features ... There is a demo of a chat application on [github](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/tree/master/demos/chat)What server technology are you using anyway ? That could help guide your choice ...

Answer (score 0):

Sure -- you can use jQuery (or any other method of accessing AJAX requests) to poll the server.  In your JavaScript, set an interval to do the polling (`setInterval(myAjaxFunction)`), and then use a method like `jQuery.get()` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to request the information from the server.

Comment: Polling certainly works, but results in a large amount of extra network traffic, and an inevitable delay before updates.

Comment: I agree fahadsadah, polling doesn't scale and there is a tradeoff between reactiveness and the number of users you can handle. Also you end up with a lot of traffic for nothing (If 1000 users poll your site every second and there is no new events during 1 minute, you get 60000 connections to your site for nothing)

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods for updating the client based on server data - one is to make the client poll the server at intervals (jQuery will let you do this with something like

```
setInterval(function() { $.post('my_url_here', myCallbackFunction) }, 1000);
```

which is arguably the easiest solution, but it's not very friendly to the server in terms of traffic and it has a number of other drawbacks which probably aren't important to this question.

If you look into websockets, node.js etc you can achieve the same thing quite easily, but it's a bigger learning curve, and you also need a server where you can run the software.
Node is a good solution which allows transparent communication between client and server, and it comes with a couple of samples like the [node demo chat room](http://chat.nodejs.org/)